# Vim how to make :g work properly with zs matches

Tags: regex, vim

I have this at the top of my file:

```
var server = require('http');
var watchr = require('watchr');
var io = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');
```

I want to transform this garbage into a proper var list:

```
var server = require('http'),
    watchr = require('watchr'),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    fs = require('fs');
```

So my first step is to find all `var` declarations in this paragraph **except the first one** and indent them. So I search for every word `var`that is preceeded by another `var` on a previous line.

Here's the regex that for some reason works:

```
\vvar\_.{-}\zs<(var)@>
```

Explanation:

```
\v          Very magic mode (make all special characters special)
var         The word var
\_          Spanning multiple lines
.           Any charaacter
{-}         Non greedy
\zs         Actually start higlighting our search here
<           A word boundary
(var)       The second occurance of the word var
@>          Treat the previous thing (var) as the whole match. Otherwise
                 Vim is too stupid to match consecutive lines and only
                 matches every other line
```

Now when I hit <kbd>n</kbd> in my file Vim correctly jumps to every single `var` statement **except** the first one. Yay!

Now let's use our trusty `:g` command to run a command on all lines matching our last regex (which would be every one except the first one, since <kbd>n</kbd> skips the first one)

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> then:

```
'<,'>g//norm>>
```

**And now I get:**

```
    var server = require('http');
    var watchr = require('watchr');
    var io = require('socket.io');
    var fs = require('fs');
```

What gives? Why did it indent my first line? How do I make `g` play nicely with `zs` or `@>` or whatever horrifying Vim regex thing I have to figure out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:global` will only take the first line of your multi-line match unless you give an offset to the command that is executed:

```
:g/^var/+norm >>
```

Result:

```
var server = require('http');
    var watchr = require('watchr');
    var io = require('socket.io');
    var fs = require('fs');
```

Anyway, I suggest this much simpler approach:

1. Join the paragraph into a single line:

   ```
   vipJ or :'{,'}j<CR>
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   var server = require('http'); var watchr = require('watchr'); var io = require('socket.io'); var fs = require('fs');
   ```
2. Split that line at the right place with the right string:

   ```
   :s/; var /,\r    /g
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   var server = require('http'),
       watchr = require('watchr'),
       io = require('socket.io'),
       fs = require('fs');
   ```

Comment: Not bad, how would you modify it to work on lines already indented by 1 or more levels?

Comment: Using your answer as a starting point this is what I came up with: `:g/^\s*var/,'}s/;\n\(\s*\)var/,\r\1   /`

Comment: the reason I wanted the `vip` is because I might have comments above / below the var statements that will get included in the paragraph, killing us all.

Comment: It should be noted that this does not match the documentation. `\zs` is supposed to be the start of the match—nothing before it counts as being part of the match, merely a “prerequisite”, of sorts. This makes it impossible to do something like using a global command with a pattern that matches the first line of a comment block that may be the first line of a file (e.g. `\v%(%^|%(^\s*\/\/.*)@<!\n)\zs(\s*)\/\/.*\n\1\/\/.*\n\1\/\/`. Sorry that's essentially impossible to parse, it's multi-line and “variabled-up” in my code)